# How to insert strings using proxy.insertText with brackets "( )" in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I'm trying to building a custom keyboard in Swift that does one thing and one thing only.. insert ¯_(ツ)_/¯upon pressing a button in a keyboard.

This is the function that I have:

```
  func buttonPressed() {
// A proxy to the text input object that the custom keyboard is interacting with. (read-only)
var proxy = textDocumentProxy as! UITextDocumentProxy

// Insert a character into the displayed text.
proxy.insertText("¯\_(ツ)_/¯")
```

}

The issue is that I keep on getting the error "Invalid escape sequence in literal"

Is there a simpler way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that

```
"¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
```

is not a valid Swift String because of the escape `\` character which needs to be, itself, escaped to be representable in a String.

Add another `\` just before the `\` character inside your String like this:

```
proxy.insertText("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯")
```

and the text will be what you expect.

```
let myString = "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
println(myString)
```

Prints

> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯